# InfoPlist.strings name convention

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization, plist

I have noticed my app does not localize the permission descriptions. I wonder it is anything related to my `info.plist` file that in fact has different name.

So if I define localized strings in `InfoPlist.strings` does the file need to comply to certain naming convention ? So in this case `info.plist` needs to stay as it is ?

How about if my `info.plist` becomes `my_app_info.plist` ? will `InfoPlist.strings` still be found ? I cannot seem to find any information regarding this and the translation doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

if you using localised string then use the following line into info.plist.
In info plist select add row then add the string **Localization native development region** select ur local language.

The second question is changing ur info.plist name, so it cant work because it is inbuilt .if u change name, the project search only info.plist.so dont change the plist name.